# ImportError: cannot import name 'Connection' from 'kombu'

Tags: python, rabbitmq, kombu

I've installed kombu. but I get the error defined in the title. my task is to send a message to a rabbitmq queue, amqp 1.0

below is the code

```
from kombu import Connection


with Connection('amqp url') as conn:
    tasks_queue =  conn.SimpleQueue('queuename')
    message ={json_message}
    control_queue.put(message)
    control_queue.close()
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: maybe you have own file or folder with name `kombu` and how it imports your file `kombu` and it can't find `Connection` in your file. But you didn't show FULL error message so we can't confirm it.

Comment: on my computer it import `Connection` without problem.

Comment: Thanks @furas. my file name was same..

Comment: Can you help me answer this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70195831/unable-to-get-a-response-from-kombu